# How to find what library was used during a program execution?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I want to know what libraries, external code were actually used during a program's execution. I am working with Inkscape's source code and interested in its command line function that converts svg to png. I want to strip out all its dependencies that's not needed in this execution path.
I am currently using gcov, but so far that only tells me about the Inkscape's code.
My development environment is Windows 2008, mingw gcc package.

Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I see you can do is to try to extract the part you are interested in and try to compile that and add dependencies on demand, the binary will actually load everything upon execution not only the needed parts AFAIK, I would recommend [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) instead or any image manuipulation library, because it would be easier to write code from scratch using libraries.

Comment: My recollection (hence not an answer) is running under gdb tells you when dynamic libraries are opened.

Answer (score 1):

[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will show you all the libraries loaded at runtime, both static and dynamic. It will also show you any handles actively touched during runtime.

[image]

You can also spawn and monitor processes from the UI, provided you have your path setup correctly.

Granted, if you have the source code, you can just search for link options during compile time, check the makefiles. For runtime, break point the LoadLibrary method in gdb. In addition, gdb also has an 'info sharedlibrary' command you can use.

Comment: Also [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) can show which files were opened, as well as which registry keys accessed.  Knowing which files were checked helps you to see why a given library was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `ldd` under MinGW just use it:
`ldd executable`    or   you may use
`objdump -p | grep  DLL`    or  even
`gprof`